# Django 1054 - Unknown Column in field list

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, data-migration

I have a Django project and I did the following:

1. Added a table with some columns
2. Insert some records into the db
3. Added a new column that I didn't realize I needed
4. Made an update to populate that column

When I did a `migrate` everything worked just fine. The new db column was created on the table and the values were populated.

When I try to run my tests, however, I now bomb out at step 2 above. When I do insert, I believe it is expecting that field to be there, even though it hasn't been created at that point yet.

What should I do?

EDIT: More info

I first made a class, class A and did a migration to create the table. Then I ran this against my db. Then I wrote a manual migration to populate some data that I knew would be there. I ra n this against the db. I realized sometime later that I need an extra field on the model. I added that field and did a migration and ran it against the database. Everything worked fine and I confirmed the new column is in the database.

Now, I went to run my tests. It tried to create the test db and bombed out, saying "1054 - Unknown column [my new column that I added to an existing table]" at the time when it is trying to run the populate data script that I wrote. It is likely looking at the table, noticing that the third field exists in the model, but not yet in the database, but I don't know how to do it better.

Comment: what is your model? did you made changes in you your model?

Comment: Care to explain what you mean by "When I do insert, I believe it is expecting that field to be there, even though it hasn't been created at that point yet" ? Unittests are independant from migrations...

Comment: How did you first create the table? Did you use a migration for it or did you go into SQL and create it manually?

Comment: I will try to address your questions in an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was because the migration scripts were getting called out of order, due to a problem I had setting them up. Everything is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the new column has a default value defined, the insert statement will expect to add data to that column. Can you move the data load to be after the second migration. (I would have commented, but do not yet have sufficient reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I faked one migration (m1), created another (m2), and then tried to migrate **m2** before I had **faked** my initial migration (m1).

So in my case I had to `migrate --fake <app name> m1` and then `migrate <app name> m2`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue all what i do to get out this issue just drop all tables in my DB and then run:

> python manage.py makemigrations

and :

> python manage.py migrate